# How to configure AutoMapper to set a property to a new instance of an object?

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to use [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) to auto-map my model to view models.

I have the following two view-models

```
public class CreateComment
{
    [Required]
    public int BlogId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public CreateComment()
    {

    }

    public CreateComment(int? blogId)
    {
        if(blogId.HasValue)
        {
            BlogId = blogId.Value;
        }
    }
}

public class BlogViewModel 
{
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    // There are more

    [Required]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [DataType("CommentDisplayViewModelTable")]
    public IEnumerable<CommentDisplayViewModel> Comments { get; set; }

    public CreateComment CreateCommentForm { get; set; }
}
```

The `CreateCommentForm` property should be a new instance every time this object is mapped. The only different when creating a new instance of `CreateCommentForm` I want the `BlogId` to get populated for me. The idea here is to have an empty `CreateCommentForm` to construct the html-form.

For now, when I configure the mapper, I ignore the `CreateCommentForm` property just to get away from running into AutoMapper exceptions. But how can I tell the auto-mapper to make a new instance every time by passing the Id property to the object?

```
mapper.CreateMap<Blog, BlogViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.CreateCommentForm , opts => opts.Ignore() );
```

How can I correctly map the `CreateCommentForm` to a new instance by passing down the `Blog.Id` property using AutoMapper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For custom object creation, you can use `ResolveUsing`.

```
mapper.CreateMap<Blog, BlogViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.CreateCommentForm , opts => opts.ResolveUsing(src => new CreateComment(src.Id)) );
```

Answer (score 3):

`ResolveUsing` is deprecated now, and Google brings me here so updating.

```
mapper.CreateMap<Blog, BlogViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.CreateCommentForm , opts => opts.MapFrom(src => new CreateComment(src.Id)) );
```

You should use `MapFrom` now, like the above example

Link for documentation; https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html